# XArray - create a dimension string1 for char data

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I try to read and write a netCDF file using xarray.

Originate file:

```
netcdf test {
dimensions:
        TIME = 1 ;
variables:
        double TIME(TIME) ;
        char VHM0_DM(TIME) ;

data:

 TIME = 25625;

 VHM0_DM =
  "D";
}
```

Python code:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset("test.nc")
ds.to_netcdf("test-write.nc")
```

Result:

```
netcdf test-write {
dimensions:
        TIME = 1 ;
        string1 = 1 ;
variables:
        double TIME(TIME) ;
                TIME:_FillValue = NaN ;
        char VHM0_DM(TIME, string1) ;
}
```

How can I prevent Xarray from:

- creating new dimension string1
- adding new variable attribute _FillValue

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is:

```
ds.to_netcdf("modified.nc", encoding={'VHM0_DM': {'dtype': 'str'}})
```

source: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2899

To remove _FillValue:

```
ds.to_netcdf("modified.nc", encoding={'TIME': {'_FillValue': None}, 'VHM0_DM': {'dtype': 'str'}})
```

source: [xarray automatically applying _FillValue to coordinates on netCDF output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693688/xarray-automatically-applying-fillvalue-to-coordinates-on-netcdf-output)

Note that it is now None instead of False.

Comment: Salut Ludo, I also had stringX dimensions being created for char array variables of length X and I wanted these variables to be stored as `string` in nc files instead of char.
So I had to specify `engine="netcdf4"` or `engine="h5netcdf"` in `to_netcdf` method to do so. 
Just wanted to point out another solution.